# Can someone help me run this program correctly

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string feet;
    string conversion;
    float value;


    cout << "What's you current unit?" ;
    cin >> conversion;


    if (value == feet)  {          //the program only runs this part and doesnt ask for input, just gives 0 as a value
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> value;

    value = value/3.281;

    cout << value << "meters";

    }
    else {
    cout<<"Enter a number: ";
    cin>> value;

    value = value*3.281;

    cout << value << "feet";

    } 

    return 0;

}
```

I left my problem in the comment above. I think I'm missing something, cause its not running completely and for some reason its giving me a value of 0.

Comment: Post your code (no links) and specify where you are having a problem.

Comment: Now that you fixed the `double` / `std::string` bug. `feet` is an empty string. Maybe you don't want a feet variable at all. You probably wanted `if (conversion == "feet")  {`

Comment: At `if (value == feet)`, `value` has no defined value, nor can it be directly compared with a `string`. This cannot compile. If your code runs, it is running a stale copy of the executable.

Comment: Your program has _undefined behavior_, You're accessing `float value;`  though it never has been initialized.
`

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in your code, the main one being that you use the value of `feet` before it is initialized. This is undefined behaviour and needs to be fixed first.

I presume you wanted something along the line of

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const double conversion = 3.281;
    std::string unit;
    double value;

    std::cout << "What's you current unit?" ;
    std::cin >> unit;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";    
    std::cin >> value;

    if (unit == "feet")  {
        std::cout << value / conversion << " meters";
    } else {
        std::cout << value * conversion << " feet";
    } 
}
```

What I changed:

- [`using namespace std;` is considered bad pratice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). I personally simply fail to see the advantage of using it.
- you had a `value == feet` when `value` was a `float` and `feet` a `string`, but there is no `operator==` for those two types.
- Magic numbers should be avoided. In different words: Never repeat a number literal in your code, instead give it a name and use that.
- Most of the code in the `if` cases was identical, so it could be moved outside.
- Be strict and consistent with names, it helps to get the logic right. Asking the user for their "unit" and storing the input as `conversion` cannot be right.

...and I almost forgot to `#include <string>` ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string conversion;
    float value;


    cout << "What's you current unit?\n";
    cin >> conversion;

    for (auto& c : conversion)
        c = tolower(c);

    if (conversion == "feet") {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> value;

        value = value / 3.281;

        cout << value << " meters";

    }
    else {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> value;

        value = value*3.281;

        cout << value << " feet";

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

If you need help understanding the code, ask in comments.

Comment: Yes because if value is in "feet" we need to print the value in "meters" and vice-versa.